# How to add Image where cursor is active inside React Quilbot

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the very basic version of React quill bot like below

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import TextEditor from '../common/TextEditor';

function PageEdit(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('This is the value intially');

    console.log("value", value)

    return (
        <div className='horizontal--center' style={{width:"50vw"}}>
      
            <TextEditor value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PageEdit;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';




function TextEditor({value, setValue}) {


    const modules = {
        // #3 Add "image" to the toolbar
        toolbar: [["bold", "italic", "image"]],
    }
    

    
    return (
     <ReactQuill theme="snow" value={value} onChange={setValue} modules={modules} />
      );
}

export default TextEditor;
```

I want to add an image at a specific point(where the cursor is active), using a button that calls an external api. Any way to achieve this?